# Remove spaces in a string

Tags: python, string, spaces

I have this function:

```
def cesar():
    n = int(raw_input("Introdueix la teva clau: "))
    f = raw_input("Introdueix la frase a xifrar: ")
    for ch in f:
        xifrat = int(ord(ch)+int(n))
        textxifrat = chr(xifrat)

        print textxifrat,
cesar()
```

And I want to remove the spaces from the output or the string. 
Problem is if I use the `.replace` Python says that it can't be applied to a str and I don't know any other way to remove those spaces.

The idea is that I want something like this: `M t q f % v z j % f x j` to become this: `Mtqf%vzj%fxj`

Comment: `"".join("M t q f % v z j % f x j".split())`

Comment: Type `Remove spaces in a string in Python` in Google.

Comment: `replace()` can't be applied to a string? What?

Comment: CAn you show  how you applied `replace` please. There is something strange so strange or you are making a typo or something.

Comment: I think he found one of the tutorials and used str instead of his declaration 
(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

Comment: Can you provide us with a trackback?

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't use `.replace()`?

```
>>> a = 'M t q f % v z j % f x j'
>>> a.replace(' ', '')
'Mtqf%vzj%fxj'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply join the string elements with empty string `""` after splitting the whole string on white spaces.:

```
>>> "".join("M t q f % v z j % f x j".split())
>>> Mtqf%vzj%fxj
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the raw input.

```
tmp = f.split()
```

Then join it

```
result = "".join(tmp)
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try?

```
def cesar():
    n = int(raw_input("Introdueix la teva clau: "))
    f = raw_input("Introdueix la frase a xifrar: ")

    print f.replace(' ', '')
```

[image: replace for python 2]

Comment: Are there any difference between your answer and my answer?

Comment: No sorry, I didn't notice it.

Comment: @MrSpeedArt can you provide a track-back?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by using replace().

```
   str ="%5 65 hfhf ? fgdgdf ";
   str = str.replace(' ','')
   print(str)
```

This code will remove blank spaces from the string.

Comment: The only real difference between this and @Kevin's earlier answer is that this one masks the `str` built-in function.